# How to delete item from SQLite PCL database on Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, xaml, xamarin

I am using one of the Xamarin.Forms tutorials on SQLite database deployment to learn how to add, get and delete items from a mobile database. At the moment, I am not quite sure how to retrieve a the Id attribute from a database item in my table to pass it through the deleteData method. Basically, after I add in a certain amount of items, I would like to delete some of the data. I have implemented a button in my XAML binding pages but I need to know how to retrieve the Id attribute of certain items and pass them into the deleteData method I have created. Can anyone help me with this?

**Here are the codes:**

*StudentDB.cs (database class)*

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using SQLite.Net;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace XamarinSqliteSample
{
public class StudentDB
{

    private SQLiteConnection _sqlconnection;

    public StudentDB ()
    {
        _sqlconnection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite> ().GetConnection ();
        _sqlconnection.CreateTable<Student> ();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        return (from t in _sqlconnection.Table<Student> ()
                select t).ToList ();
    }

    public Student GetStudent (int id)
    {
        return _sqlconnection.Table<Student> ().FirstOrDefault (t => t.Id == id);
    }

    public void DeleteStudent(int id)
    {
        _sqlconnection.Delete<Student>(id);
    }

    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        _sqlconnection.Insert(student);
    }
}
}
```

*Student.cs (item attributes for database table)*

```
using System;
using SQLite.Net.Attributes;

namespace XamarinSqliteSample
{
    public class Student
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public Student ()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

*Register.xaml.cs (C# page to create methods to that manipulate data)*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinSqliteSample
{
    public partial class Register : ContentPage
    {
        public StudentDB _studentdb;
        public Student student;

        public Register()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void adddata(object s, EventArgs args)
        {
            student = new Student();
            _studentdb = new StudentDB();
            student.Name = name.Text;
            student.Address = address.Text;
            student.Phone = phone.Text;
            student.Id++;
            _studentdb.AddStudent(student);
        }

        public void Showdata(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new StudentList());
        }

    }
}
```

*StudentList.xaml.cs (C# page to populate list view with database items)*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinSqliteSample
{
    public partial class StudentList : ContentPage
    {
        public StudentDB _database;
        public Student student;

        public StudentList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _database = new StudentDB();
            var students = _database.GetStudents();
            StudentListView.ItemsSource = students;
        }

        public void deleteData(object s, EventArgs args)
        {
            _database = new StudentDB ();
            _database.DeleteStudent (//Id attribute is passed in here);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you trigger `deleteData`, but you'll probably want to use `StudentListView.ItemSelected`, which should be one of your `Student` objects.